# Porting back from python 2.7 to 2.4.3

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.4

I'm in the circumstance where I cannot use python 2.7 and stuck with 2.4.3. I was originally trying to use str.format method, but am now trying to use the % modulo in order to back port.

Original 2.7 code:

```
LINE = "{:<6} {:34} {:18} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}\n"

def main():
    with open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
        outf.write(LINE.format("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
        for result in parse_jobfile(INPUT):
            outf.write(LINE.format(*result))
```

needed back ported 2.4.3 code:

```
LINE = "{:<6} {:34} {:18} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}\n"

def main():
    outf = open(OUTPUT, "w")
    outf.write(LINE.'%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,' % ("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
    for result in parse_jobfile(INPUT):
        outf.write(LINE.'%s'(*result))
```

But for some reason, I'm still getting errors:

```
outf.write(LINE.'%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,' % ("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what `LINE` is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Your attempted syntax makes no sense at all. What is LINE?

Comment: Looks like `LINE` used to be the string containing his `%s` values, and he just forgot to remove it when he removed `format`.

Comment: My apoliges. Code updated with LINE defined.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you didn't completely convert the syntax:

```
outf.write(LINE.'%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,' % ("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You want to have:

```
outf.write(LINE % ("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
```

Now, to fully format the line you'll have to convert the [new-style format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
LINE = "{:<6} {:34} {:18} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}\n"
```

To the equivalent [old-style format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
LINE = '%-6s %-34s %-18s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n'
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm using the example he gave, and his primary problem was the syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you previously had a template:

```
LINE = "{0}: {1}"
```

Then you put stuff in it:

```
LINE.format("foo", "bar")
```

Therefore, you need to make *two* changes:

1. Switch the placeholders in `LINE` from `{}` to `%`: `LINE = "%s: %s"`; and
2. Replace `.format` with `%`: `LINE % ("foo", "bar")`

In your current version, `LINE."%s"` makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `LINE` as follows (see the docs on [String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)):

```
LINE = "%6s %-34s %-18s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"
```

Now you can use

```
def main():
    outf = open(OUTPUT, "w")
    outf.write(LINE % ("SysNum", "Job Name", "Target Machiene", "Status", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time"))
    for result in parse_jobfile(INPUT):
        outf.write(LINE % (*result))
```

Comment: The right formatting is `LINE  = '%6s %-34s %-18s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n'`

Comment: @omri.il: Right, I had it backwards.

Comment: you still have `'%-6s'`, it should be `'%6s'`